# Building new PC, How do i move data from my old HDD to a new one?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard

The new PC will be done in the next week when the last parts I need arrive

First the build I'm gonna have: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/zV8dkT

Old Motherboard is `B75MA-P45`

I heard that changing your motherboard can cause you losing the data on your HDD, so i also got a new HDD(old one 500 GB new one 1000GB)

My thought process would be installing windows on the new HDD, get the drivers i need from the inet(like only the GPU?) and then plug in the old HDD and move the stuff I want.

Does this work or will I have the same problem that the motherboard wont recognize the stuff from my old HDD?

Answer (score 3):

Whoever told you that is incorrect. You will not loose data by changing your motherboard. If you were to *per se* boot up to any Operating Systems that was on the old HDD, issues would likely arise because the old drivers on your old HDD would not be compatible with the new hardware. If you wanted to use the old HDD for a second hard drive to your new computer and boot off of it, you would not want to boot onto any old OSs (that were installed onto the old rig) because of the issues that would arise. It may be wise, after getting everything you wanted to either wipe the disk or delete the partitions on the old HDD.

The idea you proposed will work in theory as long as there are no driver issues. The motherboard should be able to recognize the old HDD. However you may have to install drivers for it by using Windows Update or going to the Manufacturer's website; however, that is *extremely* unlikely.

Just remember when you execute your plan, plug in the old HDD before powering the computer, else the system may not detect such a change. The Motherboard and OS the majority of the time will recognize it as a drive on boot, and it will show as a volume in Windows.

EDIT requested by OP: There is no possible way to absolutely disable the ability of booting to the old HDD but it won't hurt anything to boot up to the old HDD's OS, it just may not operate due to potential driver issues due to different hardware. (Just power it off forcefully if it does happen). However, you can change the boot order of the hard drives in BIOS settings (by pressing a key at boot and navigating through it). The name of the new HDD should be listed at the top and the old HDD below it. You could also just choose Boot Selection Menu (or similar name) at startup by pressing a key.

If you want to know how to wipe the drive, after you are done using it for data recovery, you can: Open `cmd`, run `diskpart`, select a drive by using `sel disk 52` after being listed the disks with `list disk`, and running `clean`. You can also use Windows User Interface one called "Disk Management".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to disable booting Windows from the old HDD since im gonna download windows from a new cd anyways on the new HDD? I only want to use the old HDD to move the stuff i need to the new HDD then im intending to wipe it and remove it cause im gonna build a pc with my old parts for my brother

Comment: i pressed enter and accidently posted the answer before finishing

Comment: @Michael, is that a satisfactory response?

Comment: thanks again im gonna give feedback later if everything went smoothly